# Car wheels in a turn

Tags: kinematics

I know that when a car is taking a turn, the front 2 wheels trace out 2 arcs having the same centre. I also know that the steering angle for the outside wheel is more than that of the inner wheel to prevent the car from skidding. My question is during the turn do the rear wheels trace out the same arcs as the front wheels.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169274/26076

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance - I agree the two are related but I don't think the answer given in your possible dup is the answer that OP is looking for here.

Comment: If you're looking into steering geometry I should note that in real driving conditions the tires always slip slightly at a velocity dependent rate, called the slip angle.

Answer (score 2):

No they won't. while they may be circles that are centered on the same point, the radius of the four circles is different. This diagram ought to convince you:

[image]

The four wheels trace out circles with radius $r_1 ... r_4$, and each of these will be different (in general). It is possible, for certain combinations of $L$, $W$ and $D$ that the front right and bottom left wheel trace the same arc; but the others will always be (slightly) different.

$$\begin{align}\\
r_1 &= \sqrt{L^2 + D^2}\\
r_2 &= \sqrt{L^2 + (W+D)^2}\\
r_3 &= W+D\\
r_4 &= D\\
\end{align}$$